# Invalid hook call reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, runtime-error

Every time I try to render the page, this error is thrown. I tried multiple solutions but none of them worked.

Current react version is `17.0.2`, node version is `14.16.1`

Here the important code snippets:

```js
import { useAuthUser, useFeatureFlags, useUser, useClaim, firebase } from './lib'
import React from 'react'

...

function App () {
  console.log(React.version)
  const [flags, flagsLoading] = useFeatureFlags() // last executed line here

...
```

```js
import useCollection from './useCollection'

const useFeatureFlags = () => {
  const [flagData, , loading, error] = useCollection('featureFlags') // last executed line here
  ...
}

export default useFeatureFlags
```

```js
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { db } from '../firebase'

const useCollection = (path) => {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true) // here, the error is thrown
  ...
}

export default useCollection
```

I am not the author of this project, but I have to get this web app running.
Thanks for your help!

EDIT:
Here is the Stack trace and error

```
Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function 
component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.
resolveDispatcher
node_modules/react/cjs/react.development.js:1476
useState
node_modules/react/cjs/react.development.js:1507
useCollection
project/lib/build/hooks/useCollection.js:18

  15 |  * @returns [collectionDocuments, querySnapshot, loading, error]
  16 |  */
  17 | const useCollection = path => {
> 18 |   const [loading, setLoading] = (0, _react.useState)(true);
  19 |   const [ref, setRef] = (0, _react.useState)(null);
  20 |   const [querySnapshot, setQuerySnapshot] = (0, _react.useState)(null);
  21 |   const [collectionDocuments, setCollectionDocuments] = (0, _react.useState)([]);

useFeatureFlags
project/lib/build/hooks/useFeatureFlags.js:20

  17 |  * randomly determined rollout percentage.
  18 |  */
  19 | const useFeatureFlags = () => {
> 20 |   const [flagData,, loading, error] = (0, _useCollection.default)('featureFlags'); // const test = <useCollection path='featureFlags' />
  21 |   // console.log(test)
  22 | 
  23 |   const output = {};

App
src/App.js:43

  40 | 
  41 | function App () {
  42 |   console.log(React.version)
> 43 |   const [flags, flagsLoading] = useFeatureFlags()
  44 |   const [authUser, authUserLoading] = useAuthUser()
  45 |   const [user, userLoading] = useUser()
  46 |   const [claim, claimLoading] = useClaim()

./src/index.js/<
src/index.js:23

  20 | 
  21 | console.log('project id', process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID)
  22 | 
> 23 | ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'))
  24 | 

./src/index.js
http://localhost:3000/static/js/main.chunk.js:24779:30
__webpack_require__
project/web/webpack/bootstrap:851

  848 | 
  849 | __webpack_require__.$Refresh$.init();
  850 | try {
> 851 |     modules[moduleId].call(module.exports, module, module.exports, hotCreateRequire(moduleId));
      | ^  852 | } finally {
  853 |     __webpack_require__.$Refresh$.cleanup(moduleId);
  854 | }

fn
project/web/webpack/bootstrap:150

  147 |         );
  148 |         hotCurrentParents = [];
  149 |     }
> 150 |     return __webpack_require__(request);
      | ^  151 | };
  152 | var ObjectFactory = function ObjectFactory(name) {
  153 |     return {

1
http://localhost:3000/static/js/main.chunk.js:35286:18
__webpack_require__
project/web/webpack/bootstrap:851

  848 | 
  849 | __webpack_require__.$Refresh$.init();
  850 | try {
> 851 |     modules[moduleId].call(module.exports, module, module.exports, hotCreateRequire(moduleId));
      | ^  852 | } finally {
  853 |     __webpack_require__.$Refresh$.cleanup(moduleId);
  854 | }

checkDeferredModules
project/web/webpack/bootstrap:45

  42 |  }
  43 |  if(fulfilled) {
  44 |      deferredModules.splice(i--, 1);
> 45 |      result = __webpack_require__(__webpack_require__.s = deferredModule[0]);
     | ^  46 |  }
  47 | }
  48 | 

webpackJsonpCallback
project/web/webpack/bootstrap:32

  29 |  deferredModules.push.apply(deferredModules, executeModules || []);
  30 | 
  31 |  // run deferred modules when all chunks ready
> 32 |  return checkDeferredModules();
     | ^  33 | };
  34 | function checkDeferredModules() {
  35 |  var result;

(anonymous function)
http://localhost:3000/static/js/main.chunk.js:1:81
```

Comment: could you please share the full error message and stacktrace?

Comment: Could you also try to include full and complete code for the custom hooks and where they are all used or called from?

Comment: @RobinZigmond I included the stacktrace

Comment: Look at this article : https://reactjs.org/warnings/invalid-hook-call-warning.html

Comment: @SwordI I am familiar with this article. Reason 1 and 3 are not the case. Reason 2 could be the problem, but if this code breaks a Hook rule, I don't know which one and how to fix it

Comment: `useCollection` is using `useState` hook outside of a react component

Comment: you may face multiple React version error if you have a git project within a git project, or you have a src + dst directory scenarios. Do you have any of those?

Comment: if `useCollection` is a react component then why did you pass `path` directly? it should be destructured like `useCollection = ({ path }) => {...}` . and also component name should start with capital letter

Answer (score 0):

In your second and third code snippet, add
`import React from "react"`